# Configuring Websphere 7 to use single JAX-WS service instance for all requests

Tags: java, web-services, caching, jax-ws, websphere-7

While it's well known that Websphere's JAX-WS implementation is based on Axis2, I have had trouble finding information how to set "scope" for the service.

In axis 2 scope can be defined using services.xml. Is this file also available in Websphere?

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/axis2config.html

**scope:** (Optional Attribute) The time period during which runtime information of the deployed services will be available. Scope is of several types- "application", "soapsession", "transportsession", "request". The default value (if you don't enter any value) will be "request"

Comment: AFAIK, this config parameter is not part of the JAX-WS standard. Why do you want to manually set it? In general a WS should be stateless...

Comment: Because I would rather save cache in local variable that gets destroyed with the container than in a static variable that gets destroyed when class gets unloaded. As far as I know most containers create only single instance per jvm. Single instance (or pooled instances - websphere doesn't support them either) is far more efficient solution with a service that has expensive initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is possible to do what you want in WebSphere (not using services.xml): 
[Configuring the scope of a Web service port using wsadmin scripting](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/txml_scopewsadmin.html)

Did not try it myself, also, could not find such settings in the admin console or deployment descriptor of some kind but that might be possible as well.

Comment: This sounds like a plausible solution. Unfortunately I'm unable to test it before next monday. I did more research on the subject and noticed that there is a deployment descriptor configuration option for JAX-RPC through ibm-webservices-bnd.xmi (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Frwbs_assembprop.html)

Comment: Yes I noticed that also but it is only for JAX-RPC... I might have some time tomorrow to test this. Might also help for my project